# Basic Google Chrome Extension Noob Question

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a basic Google Chrome Extension that simply copies the source HTML code on the page I am on. I have never created a Chrome extension and I am really stuck and would appreciate some help. I started the extension using the Chrome guide and from what I have read on the internet is I content scripts to access the webpage. I don't know how to call the content scripts however. I tried using import statements but I received errors - I think I am really misunderstanding how the whole thing works. I am trying to also get the console log to display in the webpage console, instead of the chrome extension console.

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="changeColor"></button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
 "name": "Company Websites",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
          ],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
      "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "permissions": ["storage","declarativeContent"],
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

content.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("changeColor").addEventListener("click", handler);
  });

  // The handler also must go in a .js file
  function handler() {

    console.log("hello?");
    //somehow copy source code
  }
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({color: '#3aa757'}, function() {
      console.log("The color is green.");
    });
  });
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: {hostEquals: '* insert target web address*'},
      })
      ],
          actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can read the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: I have read it and can't get it to work, hence I posted my question on here lol

Comment: Update: I can now get content.js to trigger, but I don't know how to get a copy of the source code for the site. Once the question is complete I will upload the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make another file called load.js and do an [XML HttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp), then include it in the popup.html.

popup.html

```
<script src="load.js"></script>
```

load.js

```
  function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var data = xhttp.responseText;
}}
  xhttp.open("GET", "website url", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
loadDoc()
```

From there you can store and retrieve it in local storage, console.log(data), or use it in document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML = data